# sed match either beginning of line or character

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

I have a string of colon separated assignments, each of which is of the form `a=b`. I need to parse it to extract foo, where foo is `...:di=foo:...`. The assignment `di=foo` could happen at the beginning, in the middle, or at the end of the string.

My idea was to match either a beginning of line or a colon, then the string `di=`, then every character except a colon, then a colon or an end of line.

I've only managed to get the "every character except a colon" part to work.

Some tests:

```
echo "di=a;b:*.di=c;d:ddi=e;f" | sed "s/.*di=\([^:]*\):.*/\1/"
echo "ddi=a;b:di=c;d:*.di=e;f" | sed "s/.*di=\([^:]*\):.*/\1/"
echo "*.di=a;b:ddi=c;d:di=e;f" | sed "s/.*di=\([^:]*\):.*/\1/"
```

the first one should return `a;b`, the second one `c;d` and the third one `e;f`, but for now they all return `c;d`.

Comment: [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) might be a good alternative here ex. `mlr --fs : --onidx cut -f di`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My idea was to match either a beginning of line or a colon, then the string di=, then every character except a colon, then a colon or an end of line.

You don't need to match "then a colon or an end of line" (as in your example).

```
{
echo "di=a;b:*.di=c;d:ddi=e;f"
echo "ddi=a;b:di=c;d:*.di=e;f"
echo "*.di=a;b:ddi=c;d:di=e;f"
} | sed 's/\(^\|.*:\)di=\([^:]*\).*/\2/'
```

Outputs:

```
a;b
c;d
e;f
```

- `\(^\|.*:\)` matches the beginning of the line or any characters followed by a colon

Answer (score 1):

For cases like this, I tend to *cheat* and add a `:` to the front and end, so remove the special cases; the matching is now always for `:a=foo:`

So:

```
sed -e 's/^/:/' -e 's/$/:/' -e 's/.*:di=\([^:]*\):.*/\1/'
```

It can be optimised

```
sed -e 's/^\(.*\)$/:\1:/' -e 's/.*:di=\([^:]*\):.*/\1/'
```

The results:

```
% echo "di=a;b:*.di=c;d:ddi=e;f" | sed -e 's/^/:/' -e 's/$/:/' -e 's/.*:di=\([^:]*\):.*/\1/'
a;b
% echo "ddi=a;b:di=c;d:*.di=e;f" | sed -e 's/^/:/' -e 's/$/:/' -e 's/.*:di=\([^:]*\):.*/\1/'
c;d
echo "*.di=a;b:ddi=c;d:di=e;f" | sed -e 's/^/:/' -e 's/$/:/' -e 's/.*:di=\([^:]*\):.*/\1/'
e;f
```

Another cheat might be to convert the `:` to a newline and then it always matches `a=foo` without any `:`

```
tr : '\012' | sed -n 's/^di=//p'
```

Answer (score 1):

Posixly, it can be done as shown. Transliterate all colons to newlines
then by continuously chopping off the leading KV pair until the di= comes up.

```
{
echo "di=a;b:*.di=c;d:ddi=e;f"
echo "ddi=a;b:di=c;d:*.di=e;f"
echo "*.di=a;b:ddi=c;d:di=e;f"
} \
| sed -n 'y/:/\n/;/^di=/!D;P'

di=a;b
di=c;d
di=e;f
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk` instead of `sed`, with `:` and `=` as field delimiters,  walking through each record and printing the next field if a field is found that is `di`:

```
$ awk -F '[=:]' '{ for (i = 1; i < NF; ++i) if ($i == "di") { print $(i+1); next } }' file
a;b
c;d
e;f
```

Similarly, but instead using `:`, `=` and newlines as record separators:

```
$ awk -v RS='[=:\n]' '$0 == "di" { getline; print }' file
a;b
c;d
e;f
```

This would only work if your `awk` treats a multi-character value in `RS` as a regular expression.  This last variation would also print *each* `di` value on every original line if there are more than one such value (the first variation avoids this by calling `next`).